# What is pbzloc="22" in my HTML?

Tags: html, css, picasa

I'm using Google Picasa. The following shows up in my HTML doc, but I can't figure out what it is:

```
pbzloc="22"
```

This, for example, shows up in the following HTML

```
<p pbzloc="22" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #707070">Following up on suggestions and requests coming from users such as yourself, we&#39;ve managed to create an even better user experience, easier navigation and fast access to all analytics information for any website or mobile app.</p>
```

Can anyone tell me what this means?

Comment: Can yo show us your code? What libraries are you using? Why (and how) are you using JScript in a webpage?!

Comment: sorry if I sound confusing, I am new here.
I develop html emails, and this is the template language from "Marketo" email delivery service. But I think that this is not the part of Marketo template language, because I have found this on some other examples on google search

Comment: Upon stumbling on Google, I have found it(pbzloc or Picasa Button Zip Location) had something to do with Google Picasa location(`picasa://`): https://code.google.com/p/kashgar/source/browse/trunk/conf/picasa_mac/installer.html?r=2
http://www.file-extensions.org/pbz-file-extension
"The PBZ file extension is associated with the Google Picasa. Picasa is photo and picture image editor and manager. The PBZ files are used by Picasa Button API. They are compressed ZIP archives that contain Picasa button files (.pbf file extension) and Photoshop files (.psd file extension)."

Comment: [Meta discussion about this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262978/456814).

Answer (score 3):

Upon web researching, I found that:

1. pbzloc stands for Picasa Button Zip Location.
2. .pbz is an extension for Google Picasa.
3. They are used by Picasa Button API.
4. They are buttons for the webpage.

*"The PBZ file extension is associated with the Google Picasa. Picasa is photo and picture image editor and manager. The PBZ files are used by Picasa Button API. They are compressed ZIP archives that contain Picasa button files (.pbf file extension) and Photoshop files (.psd file extension)...."* - http://www.file-extensions.org/pbz-file-extension

Here is a kind of usage for pbzloc:

https://code.google.com/p/kashgar/source/browse/trunk/conf/picasa_mac/installer.html?r=2